# Trigger on Contact to Update the Account Fields

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, undelete

Hi I Need some help on the below scenario as i am not sure how to work in the case if the Contact Associated with the Account is deleted, Kindly help me out for the below situation,

User Story : Lets take a Account A and two its related contact as B and C.

Account is having a custom field as : Total_Amount__c and Contact is having a field called Amount__c:

```
trigger UpdateAmountOnAccount on Contact(after Insert, after update) {
List<Contact> con = [Select Id, Amount__c , Account.Total_Amount__c from Contact WHERE Account.ID!=null AND Id IN:Trigger.New];
List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
{
for(Contact s:con) {
Account a = new Account();
a.Id = s.AcccountId;
a.Total_Amount__c = a.Total_Amount__c+s.Amount___c;
System.Debug('>>>>'+a.Total_Amount__c);
acc.add(a);
}
if(acc.size() > 0){
    update acc;
}
```

Can someone help me out for this how to achieve this and when Contact will be deleted then how to handle this..

Thanks

Comment: why are you not using a roll-up summary field?

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are not setting the right value for Total_Amount__c since you're adding to the current Total_Amount__c the one of the contacts in Trigger scope.
Example1:
Account A (total_amount = 5) with total and two its related contact as C1 (amount = 2) and C2 (amount = 3).
You update the description of C1, action that will fire the trigger and update the total_amout.
The new total_amout of A will be 7 while it should remain 5.

Example2:
Account A (total_amount = 5) with total and two its related contact as C1 (amount = 2) and C2 (amount = 3).
You set the C1's amount to 5, action that will fire the trigger and update the total_amout.
The new total_amout of A will be 10 instead of 8.

You should update total_amount only if needed:

- a Contact has been deleted
- a Contact has been created
- Contact.Amount__c has changed

Keep in mind that [Trigger.New](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) isn't available in Delete triggers.

```
trigger UpdateAmountOnAccount on Contact(after insert, after update, before delete) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

    List<Contact> contactList = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.Old : Trigger.New;
    for (Contact c : contactList) {
        // Store the AccountId only if Total_Amount__c needs to be updated:
        // * a Contact has been deleted
        // * a Contact has been created
        // * Contact.Amount__c has changed
        if (Trigger.isDelete || Trigger.isInsert || (c.Amount__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Amount__c)) {
            accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accountToUpdate = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Amount__c FROM Contacts WHERE Amount__c != null) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds];
    for (Account acc : accountToUpdate) {
        Decimal total = 0;
        for (Contact c : acc.Contacts) {
            // Calculate the total amount only for the Contacts that haven't been deleted
            if (Trigger.isAfter || !Trigger.oldMap.containsKey(c.Id)) {
                total += c.Amount__c;
            }
        }
        acc.Total_Amount__c = total; 
    }
    
    update accountToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this solution ... Can you please help me with this line as i am not able to understand : List<Contact> contactList = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.Old : Trigger.New;